# What jars are required to use the latest Mockito?

Tags: eclipse, jar, mockito

I'm using an Eclipse project and don't want to use a Maven pom.  I want to drop the jars needed for Mockito into a directory and reference them from Eclipse build properties. But Mockito.org doesn't supply a download link nor mention what jars are needed to get Mockito running.

How do I determine what jars I need to download?

Answer (score 2):

Mockito.org is mysteriously evasive about what Jars are needed for specific releases.  They really want people using the .pom, but sometimes we don't wanna use Maven.  (Developers are capricious and stubborn after all.)

Here's how to derive what jars you'll need if you're willing to read a .pom:
Go to Maven.org and type "mockito" into the search box.  Look for the latest version of a "mockito*" in the "artifact ID" column.  Decide which .jar "looks right."  In this case I used mockito-core.  Click on the "jar" link and now you've got your first jar.

**But you need to get the dependencies:**
Click on the link to the .pom and look at the listed dependencies.  You'll see listed artifact-ids such as byte-buddy, byte-buddy-agent, and objenesis.

Using the maven.org search box, enter in the artifact-id and download the jar for each of them.  Put them all together in a directory and change your build properties so you can use Mockito in your Eclipse project.

Comment: Follow these steps for `mockito-junit-jupiter-*` if you use JUnit 5. Since it has the Jupiter name in it, I can only assume that this library offers separate support from JUnit 4 in their `mockito-core-*` library.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are looking for

mockito-core.jar

and on top of that, you also want:

- mockito-core-sources.jar
- mockito-core-javadoc.jar

It **often** helps to have the source code, or at least the javadoc content at your fingertips within your IDE.

Comment: I wish it were that easy.  In the past that might have been the case but Mockito 2.10 won't work with just that jar. It depends on byte-buddy, byte-buddy-agent, and objenesis or you'll be getting ClassNotFoundExceptions.